# MUSIC Algorithm Spectrum Python Implementation

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, linear-algebra, frequency-analysis

I am working on a small radar project that can measure the Doppler shift created by the heart and chest. Since I know the number of sources in advance, I decided to choose the MUSIC Algorithm for spectral analysis. I am acquiring data and sending it to Python for analysis. However, my Python code is saying that the power for ALL frequencies of a signal with two mixed sinusoids of frequency 1 Hz and 2 Hz is equal. My code is linked here with a sample output:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath
import scipy


N = 5

z = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, num=N)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi * z) + np.sin(1 * np.pi * z) + np.random.random(N) * 0.3 # sample signal

conj = np.conj(x);

l = len(conj)

sRate = 25 # sampling rate

p = 2
flipped  = [0 for h in range(0, l)]

flipped = conj[::-1]


acf = signal.convolve(x,flipped,'full')


a1 = scipy.linalg.toeplitz(c=np.asarray(acf),r=np.asarray(acf))#autocorrelation matrix that will be decomposed into eigenvectors

eigenValues,eigenVectors = LA.eig(a1)

idx = eigenValues.argsort()[::-1]
eigenValues = eigenValues[idx]
eigenVectors = eigenVectors[:,idx]

idx = eigenValues.argsort()[::-1]

eigenValues = eigenValues[idx]# soriting the eigenvectors and eigenvalues from greatest to least eigenvalue
eigenVectors = eigenVectors[:,idx]

signal_eigen = eigenVectors[0:p]#these vectors make up the signal subspace, by using the number of principal compoenets, 2 to split the eigenvectors
noise_eigen = eigenVectors[p:len(eigenVectors)]# noise subspace

for f in range(0, sRate):
    sum1 = 0

    frequencyVector = np.zeros(len(noise_eigen[0]), dtype=np.complex_)

    for i in range(0,len(noise_eigen[0])):
        frequencyVector[i] = np.conjugate(complex(np.cos(2 * np.pi * i * f), np.sin(2 * np.pi * i * f)))#creating a frequency vector with e to the 2pi *k *f and taking the conjugate of the each component

    for u in range(0,len(noise_eigen)):
        sum1 +=  (abs(np.dot(np.asarray(frequencyVector).transpose(), np.asarray(   noise_eigen[u]) )))**2 # summing the dot product of each noise eigenvector and frequency vector taking the absolute value and squaring

    print(1/sum1)
    print("\n")


"""
(OUTPUT OF THE ABOVE CODE)
0.120681885992
0
0.120681885992
1
0.120681885992
2
0.120681885992
3
0.120681885992
4
0.120681885992
5
0.120681885992
6
0.120681885992
7
0.120681885992
8
0.120681885992
9
0.120681885992
10
0.120681885992
11
0.120681885992
12
0.120681885992
13
0.120681885992
14
0.120681885992
15
0.120681885992
16
0.120681885992
17
0.120681885992
18
0.120681885992
19
0.120681885992
20
0.120681885992
21
0.120681885992
22
0.120681885992
23
0.120681885992
24

Process finished with exit code 0


"""
```

Here is the formula for the MUSIC Algorithm:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5EG2FEWlIZwYmkteUludHNXS0k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, the problem is that **i** and **f** are both integers.  Thus, 2*π*i*f is an integral multiple of 2π.  Allowing for a tiny bit of round-off error, this gives you a cosine very close to 1.0 and a sin very close to 0.0.  These values yield virtually no variation in **frequencyVector** from one iteration to the next.

I also see a problem in that you set up your **signal_eigen matrix**, but never use it.  Isn't the signal itself required by this algorithm?  As a result, all you're doing is sampling the noise at intervals of 2πi.

---

Let's try chopping up one cycle into **sRate** evenly-spaced sampling points.  This results in spikes at 0.24 and 0.76 (out of the range 0.0 - 0.99).  Does this match your intuition about how this should work?

```
signal_eigen = eigenVectors[0:p]
noise_eigen = eigenVectors[p:len(eigenVectors)]     # noise subspace
print "Signal\n", signal_eigen
print "Noise\n", noise_eigen

for f_int in range(0, sRate * p + 1):
    sum1 = 0
    frequencyVector = np.zeros(len(noise_eigen[0]), dtype=np.complex_)
    f = float(f_int) / sRate

    for i in range(0,len(noise_eigen[0])):
        # create a frequency vector with e to the 2pi *k *f and taking the conjugate of the each component
        frequencyVector[i] = np.conjugate(complex(np.cos(2 * np.pi * i * f), np.sin(2 * np.pi * i * f)))
        # print f, i, np.pi, np.cos(2 * np.pi * i * f)

    # print frequencyVector

    for u in range(0,len(noise_eigen)):
        # sum the squared dot product of each noise eigenvector and frequency vector.
        sum1 += (abs(np.dot(np.asarray(frequencyVector).transpose(), np.asarray( noise_eigen[u]) )))**2

    print f, 1/sum1
```

Output

```
Signal
[[ -3.25974386e-01   3.26744322e-01  -5.24205744e-16  -1.84108176e-01
   -7.07106781e-01  -6.86652798e-17   2.71561652e-01   3.78607948e-16
    4.23482344e-01]
 [  3.40976541e-01   5.42419088e-02  -5.00000000e-01  -3.62655793e-01
   -1.06880232e-16   3.53553391e-01  -3.89304223e-01  -3.53553391e-01
    3.12595284e-01]]
Noise
[[ -3.06261935e-01  -5.16768248e-01   7.82012443e-16  -3.72989138e-01
   -3.12515753e-16  -5.00000000e-01   5.19589478e-03  -5.00000000e-01
   -2.51205535e-03]
 [  3.21775774e-01   8.19916352e-02   5.00000000e-01  -3.70053622e-01
    1.44550753e-16   3.53553391e-01   4.33613344e-01  -3.53553391e-01
   -2.54514258e-01]
 [ -4.00349040e-01   4.82750272e-01  -8.71533036e-16  -3.42123880e-01
   -2.68725150e-16   2.42479504e-16  -4.16290671e-01  -4.89739378e-16
   -5.62428795e-01]
 [  3.21775774e-01   8.19916352e-02  -5.00000000e-01  -3.70053622e-01
   -2.80456498e-16  -3.53553391e-01   4.33613344e-01   3.53553391e-01
   -2.54514258e-01]
 [ -3.06261935e-01  -5.16768248e-01   1.08027782e-15  -3.72989138e-01
   -1.25036869e-16   5.00000000e-01   5.19589478e-03   5.00000000e-01
   -2.51205535e-03]
 [  3.40976541e-01   5.42419088e-02   5.00000000e-01  -3.62655793e-01
   -2.64414807e-16  -3.53553391e-01  -3.89304223e-01   3.53553391e-01
    3.12595284e-01]
 [ -3.25974386e-01   3.26744322e-01  -4.97151703e-16  -1.84108176e-01
    7.07106781e-01  -1.62796158e-16   2.71561652e-01   2.06561854e-16
    4.23482344e-01]]
0.0 0.115397176866
0.04 0.12355071192
0.08 0.135377011677
0.12 0.136669716901
0.16 0.148772917566
0.2 0.195742574649
0.24 0.237792763699
0.28 0.181921271171
0.32 0.12959840172
0.36 0.121070836044
0.4 0.139075881122
0.44 0.139216853056
0.48 0.117815494324
0.52 0.117815494324
0.56 0.139216853056
0.6 0.139075881122
0.64 0.121070836044
0.68 0.12959840172
0.72 0.181921271171
0.76 0.237792763699
0.8 0.195742574649
0.84 0.148772917566
0.88 0.136669716901
0.92 0.135377011677
0.96 0.12355071192
```

---

I'm also unsure of the correct implementation; having more of the paper for formula context would help.  I'm not certain about the range and sampling of the **f** values.  When I worked on FFT software, **f** was swept over the wave form in small increments, typically **2π/sRate**.

---

I'm not getting those distinctive spikes now -- not sure what I did before.  I made a small parametrized change, adding a num_slice variable:

```
num_slice = sRate * N

for f_int in range(0, num_slice + 1):
    sum1 = 0
    frequencyVector = np.zeros(len(noise_eigen[0]), dtype=np.complex_)
    f = float(f_int) / num_slice
```

You can compute it however you like, of course, but the ensuing loop runs through just the one cycle.  Here's my output:

```
0.0 0.136398199883
0.008 0.136583829848
0.016 0.13711117893
0.024 0.137893463111
0.032 0.138792904453
0.04 0.139633157335
0.048 0.140219450839
0.056 0.140365986349
0.064 0.139926689416
0.072 0.138822121693
0.08 0.137054535152
0.088 0.13470609994
0.096 0.131921188389
0.104 0.128879079596
0.112 0.125765649854
0.12 0.122750994163
0.128 0.119976226317
0.136 0.117549199221
0.144 0.115546862203
0.152 0.114021482029
0.16 0.113008398728
0.168 0.112533730494
0.176 0.112621097254
0.184 0.113296863522
0.192 0.114593615279
0.2 0.116551634665
0.208 0.119218062482
0.216 0.12264326497
0.224 0.126873674308
0.232 0.131940131305
0.24 0.137840727381
0.248 0.144517728837
0.256 0.151830000359
0.264 0.159526062508
0.272 0.167228413981
0.28 0.174444818009
0.288 0.180621604818
0.296 0.185241411664
0.304 0.187943197745
0.312 0.188619481273
0.32 0.187445977812
0.328 0.184829467764
0.336 0.181300320748
0.344 0.177396490666
0.352 0.173576190425
0.36 0.170171993077
0.368 0.167379359825
0.376 0.165265454514
0.384 0.163786582966
0.392 0.16280869726
0.4 0.162130870823
0.408 0.161514399035
0.416 0.160719375729
0.424 0.159546457646
0.432 0.157875982968
0.44 0.155693319037
0.448 0.153091632029
0.456 0.150251065569
0.464 0.147402137481
0.472 0.144785618099
0.48 0.14261932062
0.488 0.141076562538
0.496 0.140275496354
0.504 0.140275496354
0.512 0.141076562538
0.52 0.14261932062
0.528 0.144785618099
0.536 0.147402137481
0.544 0.150251065569
0.552 0.153091632029
0.56 0.155693319037
0.568 0.157875982968
0.576 0.159546457646
0.584 0.160719375729
0.592 0.161514399035
0.6 0.162130870823
0.608 0.16280869726
0.616 0.163786582966
0.624 0.165265454514
0.632 0.167379359825
0.64 0.170171993077
0.648 0.173576190425
0.656 0.177396490666
0.664 0.181300320748
0.672 0.184829467764
0.68 0.187445977812
0.688 0.188619481273
0.696 0.187943197745
0.704 0.185241411664
0.712 0.180621604818
0.72 0.174444818009
0.728 0.167228413981
0.736 0.159526062508
0.744 0.151830000359
0.752 0.144517728837
0.76 0.137840727381
0.768 0.131940131305
0.776 0.126873674308
0.784 0.12264326497
0.792 0.119218062482
0.8 0.116551634665
0.808 0.114593615279
0.816 0.113296863522
0.824 0.112621097254
0.832 0.112533730494
0.84 0.113008398728
0.848 0.114021482029
0.856 0.115546862203
0.864 0.117549199221
0.872 0.119976226317
0.88 0.122750994163
0.888 0.125765649854
0.896 0.128879079596
0.904 0.131921188389
0.912 0.13470609994
0.92 0.137054535152
0.928 0.138822121693
0.936 0.139926689416
0.944 0.140365986349
0.952 0.140219450839
0.96 0.139633157335
0.968 0.138792904453
0.976 0.137893463111
0.984 0.13711117893
0.992 0.136583829848
1.0 0.136398199883
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are 100% right, the frequency-vector is just resulting in values of 1 and 0 for cos and sin respectively. However, I am not sure how to fix that based on the formula in the picture. Also the signal_eigen matrix is not used because the MUSIC Algorithm is based on the fact that the signal is orthogonal to the noise. By doing the dot product between the noise vector and a potential frequency one can see if the result is orthogonal or zero meaning its part of the signal subspace. For this reason, the signal subspace is separated from the noise subspace.

Comment: Sure here is a link to a book with the MUSIC Algorithm: http://dsp-book.narod.ru/302.pdf and it starts on page 288

Comment: Thanks.  I took a run through it; it appears that f is supposed to be F-sub-i / F-sub-k, which seems to translate to 2πf / sRate ... ?  That would mean one run from 0 to 2π, taken in sRate sampling spots (omitting either endpoint).

Comment: Yup definitely, these results seem much better, however shouldn't there only be spikes at 1 and 0.5 based on the initial sinusoids? Also why did you go from 0 to sRate * p(2) + 1?

Comment: Oh ... I used that range because I misinterpreted the proper upper limit.  **sRate** should do, as the sequence simply repeats after that.

Comment: I agree on the spikes: they should be at the mapped values for 1 and 2.

Comment: So why aren't the values in that range? Does the upper bound have to be sRate^2 so the f can go to 25? Also, in MATLAB, the outputs of the MUSIC Algorithm are really smooth not so jagged like this; is it because ,in MATLAB, the step size is really small for the frequency sweep? http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pmusic.html#examples

Comment: At the moment, f runs 0-24; you can keep the "+1" to get it all the way to 25, if you want.  I suspect that MATLAB MUSIC does use smaller time steps (sampling rate).  I'll give that a try and update the solution.

Comment: Right but shouldn't the frequency scale run from 0- 25/2? Right now it is running from 0 - 1, right?. Also I ran the code and plotted it, and I am getting a wave with multiple bumps, but not two distinctive peaks. Here is a pic: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5EG2FEWlIZwaEhaZHBULV95Z2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also I was looking into eigenvectors for Python and it turns out there is a specific function for decomposing a symmetric matrix, it is scipy.linalg.eigh, it might make a difference, I am not sure. Also, could you send me your complete code?

Comment: All of my changes are posted; I left in the eigenvector assignments where the overlap occurs.  Everything above that is your code.

Comment: Right, so I was also thinking 5 samples is pretty low, so I increased the sample size to 100, but there is still the issue of in-distinctive peaks.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5EG2FEWlIZwTUR5U0RnbTZ6RHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the graphic; that looks about right: symmetric about the midpoint of the phase, and showing he variability I see in the printed data.  I'm afraid I don't have time to dig into this (busy week-plus starting today), but I hope I've been of some help.

Comment: Yup definitely, thanks for the help. I think at this point there must be a mathematical error, or something to do with the eigenvectors I may need to fix.

Comment: Right.  I printed them out, hopeful that the values might tell *you* something.

Comment: Just a little bit interesting, I found that if you divide the  sum1 += (abs(np.dot(np.asarray(frequencyVector).transpose(), np.asarray( noise_eigen[u]) )))**2 by the eigenvalue you get a much clearer plot. It is unsettling to see an FFT perform much better than this, so I guess there must be some error we are overlooking.

Comment: @Prune I'm working on implementing this exact algorithm, and I've tried your proposed solution above with some modifications, can you help me with that, please?